# designing hover slider drop down menu in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a simple hover slider, in which if i hover on it, a drop down menu should slide downwards, and the movement i hover the background color of the button should also change.

while designing this i created a normal button gave it some color now when i am trying to hover on it,its not changing its color.I wrapped my slider button and slider contents in slider class, button have class of slidercontact and slider contents are in slidercontent class(which is not shown in the following code).

i expected the color change, but no color was changed.

```css
.media {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(43, 74, 111, 0.2);
}

.contents {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(27, 5, 58);
  border: solid 10px rgba(3, 35, 54, 0.6);
  padding: -3%;
}

.slidercontact {
  width: 80px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: rgb(7, 18, 58);
  background-color: rgba(122, 134, 173, 0.5);
  border: 3px solid rgb(6, 21, 57);
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 1.9%;
  margin-top: -5%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.slider:hover .slidercontact {
  background-color: rgb(277, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="media">
  <video src="video.mov" autoplay loop muted></video>`
</div>
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="contents">
  <h1>Registration Page</h1>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <button class="slidercontact">EmailID</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.background` has a `z-index: 1`, effectively covering the page and catching all mouse events, including `hover`. To let the `pointer-events` pass through it, give it a

```
pointer-events: none;
```

See it working:

```css
.media {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
  pointer-events: none;               /* <=== here */
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(43, 74, 111, 0.2);
}

.contents {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(27, 5, 58);
  border: solid 10px rgba(3, 35, 54, 0.6);
  padding: -3%;
}

.slidercontact {
  width: 80px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: rgb(7, 18, 58);
  background-color: rgba(122, 134, 173, 0.5);
  border: 3px solid rgb(6, 21, 57);
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 1.9%;
  margin-top: -5%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.slider:hover .slidercontact {
  background-color: rgb(277, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="media">
  <video src="video.mov" autoplay loop muted></video>`
</div>
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="contents">
  <h1>Registration Page</h1>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <button class="slidercontact">EmailID</button>
</div>
```